# How to reference a box collider in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference

I'm trying to make an object's box collider turn off but it doesn't seem that I referenced the box collider correctly. I want to know how to reference a box collider, and I'm not talking about the object that the script is attached to I'm talking about referencing any box collider of any game object available. Here's my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OpenDangerGate : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject obj;
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject obj1;
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject invisibleWall;
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject invisibleWall1;
    public BoxCollider plank;
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        obj.SetActive(false);
        obj1.SetActive(true);
        invisibleWall.SetActive(false);
        invisibleWall1.SetActive(false);
        plank.SetActive(false);
    }
```

Comment: Do you maybe mean to use `plank.gameObject.SetActive(false);` or `plank.enabled = false;` ? It is possible that you get a compiler error so your script is not recompiled => your new added field not yet appearing in the Inspector ... So currently I would vote to close this question as typo-based since if you correct that compiler error it should do exactly what you ask for

Comment: @derHugo Oh I get it now! I had to use plank.enabled = false and not plank.SetActive(false) coz it's not a game object. Thx for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need [FindObjectsOfTypeAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll.html)

You would get the box colliders like this:

You can set a public variable and assign it in the start:

```
public class OpenDangerGate : MonoBehaviour
{
     public BoxCollider[] allBoxColliders;

    void Start() {
        allBoxColliders = FindObjectsOfType<BoxCollider>();
    }
}
```

To loop through them and disable for example:

```
foreach (var collider in allBoxColliders) {
    collider.enabled = false; 
}
```

Edit. Code to drag a box collider from the scene:

```
public class OpenDangerGate : MonoBehaviour
{
     [SerializeField]
     BoxCollider boxCollider;
     
     //for example to disable the collider
     void OnMouseDown()
     {
          boxCollider.enabled = false;
     }
}
```

If you disable the gameObject, the collider will also disable.

Comment: I have to add this to the start function right? In this case I keep my "public GameObject plank;" there or not? When I want to set this BoxCollider as active or not active how do I do that now? I tried to put your code in the start function and didn't change anything else in the code and it still didn't work.

Comment: Um IDK I think you misunderstood the question. I tried it this time and it didn't give me an error but it also didn't give me the slot where I can grab the box collider from an object to the script. I'll try to make it clear this time. Just like I referenced some Game objects in the script so I can drag one to it's slot in the script I want to do the same thing with a box collider in a game object. And I'm not talking about the box collider of the object the script is attached to. I'm talking about the box collider of another object.

Comment: Your sentence " I'm talking about referencing any box collider of any game object available" misguided me. I edited the answer with what I think is what you want. I did not check if it compiles, but you should be able to figure small compilation issues out :)